# Efficient dynamic method of sourcing javascript data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have the following code:

```
var dataSet = [
    [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
    [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
    [ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ],
    [ "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060" ],
    [ "Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700" ],
    [ "Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000" ],
    [ "Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500" ],
    [ "Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900" ],
    [ "Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500" ],
    [ "Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600" ],
    [ "Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560" ],
    [ "Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000" ],
    [ "Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600" ],
    [ "Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2012/12/18", "$313,500" ],
    [ "Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2010/03/17", "$385,750" ],
    [ "Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2012/11/27", "$198,500" ],
    [ "Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2010/06/09", "$725,000" ]
   
]
;
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." },
            { title: "Start date" },
            { title: "Salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

I removed the hardcoded lists and I have a python script spitting it out instead.  All the python script does is just output text that looks exactly as the hardcoded lists above:

```
[ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ]
[ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ]
[ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ]
[ "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29" "$433,060" ]
[ "Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700" ]
[ "Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000" ]
[ "Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500" ]
[ "Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900" ]
[ "Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500" ]
[ "Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600" ]
[ "Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560" ]
[ "Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000" ]
[ "Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600" ]
[ "Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2012/12/18", "$313,500" ]
[ "Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2010/03/17", "$385,750" ]
[ "Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2012/11/27", "$198,500" ]
[ "Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2010/06/09", "$725,000" ]
```

So, to get this to show up correctly on my webpage, I'm doing this:

```
var dataSet = [ mylists.split("\n")[0].split(","), mylists.split("\n")[1].split(",")] ;
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." },
            { title: "Start date" },
            { title: "Salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Clearly, this is not efficient as I'm still having to hardcode the retrieval of values in the list.  How do I do this correctly via a for loop?  I've tried many different for loops, none of which worked.  I could only get the first row to show up (in the best case so far).

I tried a for loop similar to this but the results aren't correct.  It's not recognizing the rows:

```
function getvals(mylists) {
    var newvar = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < mylists.length; i++) {
        newvar.push(mylists[i].split(","));
        
    }
    return newvar;
}

var automated_list = getvals(mylists);

var dataSet = [ automated_list ] ;
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." },
            { title: "Start date" },
            { title: "Salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: why the python produce that output at first place?

Comment: if you make it produce something like json then all you need is json.parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can parse the data line-by-line with `map`, but why you don't make the python script return json at first place?

```js
let data = `[ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ]
[ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ]
[ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ]`

console.log(data.split('\n').map(JSON.parse))
```

---

If the data is itself valid json

```js
// if the data is itself valid json
let data = `[
   [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
   [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
   [ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ]
]`

// it'd be easier
console.log(JSON.parse(data))
```